# Jenkins Run Shell Inside Running Container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run some commands inside an already running container. How can I do this?

I know I can do:
docker.image(...).inside(...) {

}

But this creates a container and then runs the sh steps in it. Is there a way to do this but inside a container already running?

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process; how would you run an additional command inside a non-container process?  (Why is launching a new container bad?  Is there a reason to need a container at all?)

Comment: I'm trying a Dockerized Jenkins SSH Agent in Windows Containers with binding of the docker names pipeline. Using the agent and doing "docker ps" y get all containers from the host. And I can do docker run, but somehow when i use .inside {..} the pipeline gets frozen. I tested and doing a docker run and then exec into that container does not give me any problems. I wanted to achieve that if possible.

Comment: @Rolando Why not use regular docker commands then? `docker exec my_container <command>`